# Should i adjust SO_RCVBUF to a very small size， when incoming data is very small

Tags: sockets, tcp, boost-asio

If a tcp server has thousands of concurrent connections， 
and each tcp client sends very small data occasionally, 
Should i adjust SO_RCVBUF to a very small size to save precious memory?

p.s. the size of data is less than 30 byte, 
     the time interval of data tranfer is larger than 5 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not. You won't be able to decrease it below the platform minimum anyway, which will be at least 8k.